Append and modify a flag onClick to Parent element if same element is present on Child element in react js
I want to modify a disabled flag to parent element which has same Id in child element and create a new array which is selected onClick.
parent = [
    {
        "title": "Create User",
        "id": "1",
        "level": 2,
        "child": [
            {
                "title": "View User",
                "id": "2",
                **"disabled": true,**
                "level": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "View User",
        "id": "2",
        "disabled": false,
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "Toggle User",
        "id": "3",
        "level": 2,
        "child": [
            {
                "title": "View User",
                "id": "2",
                "disabled": true,
                "level": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]

Lets suppose,

I selected View User which has id:"2" only and nothing else. disabled flag is "false" So it should allow to be selected.
I selected Create User with id:"1", so the child element also gets selected and same id in level2 should be marked as disabled true. Because if user has create permissions then they must also have view permissions.
Again if user deselects Create user then the parent element with view should be false, so that user can remove view permission.

I tried thr code below. It is working for Point 1 & 2, but for 3 it is not working.
Note, currentItemId = "1" (Create User)
tempSubId = "2" (View User)
const updateProperty = (**parent**, currentItemId, tempSubId) => {
**parent**.forEach((item) => {
      if(tempSubId === item.id){
        item["disabled"] = !item.disabled
      }
    })
  }

Any help would be appreciated.
